# Import many tables in Logstash file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have many tables to import from MySql to Elasticsearch using logstash and I've imported one table which was succesfull. Some of them are not linked to each other which means that's not possible to make join in query for logstash. Any ideas ?

Comment: how do you want to merge this data before to output to elasitcsearch? If you want keep just one mysql input you could consider to use `UNION ALL` to select from multiple table (using the same number of columns) and then to use the aggregate filter plugin to compose events.

Comment: I've found the solution. Thanks for your help :)